# How to fill missing values with multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of movies with several columns listing actors/actresses appearing in the movie. The data is messy and sometimes the first column contains a missing value but the second contains an actor's name. I want to keep all the actor columns but move each non-missing value to the earliest column. For example:

```
movies <- data.frame(actor1=c("A","B",NA,"C",NA), actor2=c(NA, "Z", "W", NA, "X"), actor3=c("L","M","N","O","P"))

  actor1 actor2 actor3
1      A   <NA>      L
2      B      Z      M
3   <NA>      W      N
4      C   <NA>      O
5   <NA>      X      P
```

Should become:

```
  actor1 actor2 actor3
1      A      L   <NA>
2      B      Z      M
3      W      N   <NA>
4      C      O   <NA>
5      X      P   <NA>
```

`coalesce()` will pull W and X to the first column. Perfect. But how do I do the same for subsequent columns? For example, since W was pulled from actor2 to actor1, I now want the third row of actor2 to have the value N, not W.

Comment: Try  `movies[] <- t(apply(movies, 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to loop over the rows, concatenate (`c`) the non-NA elements followed by the `NA` elements

```
movies[] <- t(apply(movies, 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
movies
# actor1 actor2 actor3
#1      A      L   <NA>
#2      B      Z      M
#3      W      N   <NA>
#4      C      O   <NA>
#5      X      P   <NA>
```

---

Also, if it is a subset of columns, then use `startsWith`

```
i1 <- startsWith(names(movies), "actor")
```

and update only those columns

```
movies[i1] <-  t(apply(movies[i1], 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
```

Answer (score 1):

A way identifying the `actors*` columns first (probably there are columns of different kind). Basically this rips out the `NA`s off the rows and harmonizes the `length`s afterwards.

```
ac.cols <- grep("^actor\\d$", names(movies), value=TRUE)
movies[ac.cols] <- lapply(movies[ac.cols], as.character)

res <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                        lapply(1:nrow(movies), function(m) 
                          `length<-`(
                            na.omit(unlist(movies[m, ac.cols])),
                            ncol(movies)))), 
                ac.cols)
res
#   actor1 actor2 actor3
# 1      A      L   <NA>
# 2      B      Z      M
# 3      W      N   <NA>
# 4      C      O   <NA>
# 5      X      P   <NA>
```