# Fill in missing data from multiple columns using case_when in R

Tags: r

I have data with 4 columns that each contain data for Weeks as shown below

```
df <- data.frame (column1  = c("W12", "W18", "", "W13", "", ""),
                  column2 = c("W12", "W18", "W13", "W25", "", ""),
                  column3 = c("", "", "", "", "", "W26"),
                  column4 = c("", "", "", "", "W23", ""))
```

I want to create a new column that takes the Week from the columns in a specific order. If the Week is present in column1, use Week from column1, but if not proceed to column2, then 3, then 4.

So ideally the data is:

```
complete:
W12
W18
W13
W13
W23
W26
```

I first tried this with multiple if_then statements, but it was overwriting the data and providing incorrect final information.

I am now trying with case_when, but getting the error:

"Case 1 (`column1 == ""`) must be a two-sided formula, not a logical vector."

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(complete = case_when(column1 == "", ~column2,
                              column2 == "", ~column3,
                              column3 == "", ~column4))
```

I think this has something to do with how I am referencing the column, but can´t figure out how to re-write.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58545715/how-to-fill-missing-values-with-multiple-columns-in-r) is similar, but I am trying to create a new column not overwrite values in the first column.

Comment: remove the commas before the tildes (e.g. `column1 == "" ~ column2,`), and set a default of "" maybe?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind converting `""` to `NA`, then you could use either `data.table`'s or `dplyr`'s coalesce implementations:

```
df[df == ""] <- NA # Technically NA_character_ but R will understand

data.table::fcoalesce(df)
do.call(dplyr::coalesce, df) # dplyr::coalesce(!!!df2) will also work

# [1] "W12" "W18" "W13" "W13" "W23" "W26"
```

With a for loop:

```
complete <- vector("character", nrow(df))
for (col in names(df)) {
  incompl <- which(complete == "")
  if (!length(incompl)) break
  complete[incompl] <- df[[col]][incompl]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach with `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(complete = c_across(everything())[which.max(c_across(everything()) != "")])

  column1 column2 column3 column4 complete
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   
1 "W12"   "W12"   ""      ""      W12     
2 "W18"   "W18"   ""      ""      W18     
3 ""      "W13"   ""      ""      W13     
4 "W13"   "W25"   ""      ""      W13     
5 ""      ""      ""      "W23"   W23     
6 ""      ""      "W26"   ""      W26
```

Comment: This is a few unfamiliar functions to me, but which.max looks like it will choose the max value? But the data is character and I want to go in the order of the columns, not necessarily the order of the weeks. Also I have other columns in the dataset with data on age, sex, and other dates that I don´t want it to take into account so not sure if using across everything will have negative effects.

Comment: This returns the first non-empty value from the range of columns. `everything()` can be replaced by `c_across(starts_with("column"))`or the precise range of columns.

Comment: Thanks that worked when I moved the columns to the front using select and then specified the column numbers!

df <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(complete = c_across(1:4)[which.max(c_across(1:4) != "")])